# Load HTML5 Drag and Drop Q&A in Interactive PDF

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

We currently have an interactive pdf book with hotspots for students teaching them social science. It loads the following data all made with Flash in pop-ups once a hotspot is clicked in the pdf:

1. Bar Graphs that grows on loading popup
2. Titles that load on click like you can do in PowerPoint. One title below the other. So each click loads another title
3. Drag and drop answering of questions - Preferably option to drag answer to question and make it bounce when incorrect.
4. Videos

We would like all of it to be made with HTML5, but we are not certain we can do all this and make it as good as it is made in Flash now.

*Let's focus on one item I need to get running with HTML5*

**Drag and drop Q & A**

Drag and drop answering of questions does not seem to exist according to [(jQuery plugin to) drag & drop answers in multiple choice quiz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769639/jquery-plugin-to-drag-drop-answers-in-multiple-choice-quiz) . Drag and drop of course does, but perhaps there is more code out there that I can use to drag an answer to the question and get a confirmation that the answer is correct?

**Update**

Moodle does use drag and drop matching for 2 years or so, so it is possible: https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=165923 Will need to see if I can refactor their code for WordPress or standalone use.

Has anyone experience with this? Is it possible to make this script or another script make a dragged answer bounce when it is dragged to the wrong box or area?

Comment: These are actually a whole bunch of unrelated questions. You should ask them separately.

Comment: Will adjust the question. Thanks for feedback

Comment: @Philipp adjusted the question. Will also make some other soon.